# TSQL Update Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

Ok SQL Server fans I have an issue with a legacy stored procedure that sits inside of a SQL Server 2008 R2 Instance that I have inherited also with the PROD data which to say the least is horrible. Also, I can NOT make any changes to the data nor the table structures.

So here is my problem, the stored procedure in question runs daily and is used to update the `employee` table. As you can see from my example the incoming data (`#New_Employees`) contains the updated data and I need to use it to update the data in the `Employee` data is stored in the #Existing_Employees table. Throughout the years different formatting of the `EMP_ID` value has been used and must be maintained as is (I fought and lost that battle). Thankfully, I have been successfully in changing the format of the `EMP_ID` column in the `#New_Employees` table (Yeah!) and any new records will use this format thankfully!

So now you may see my problem, I need to update the `ID` column in the `#New_Employees` table with the corresponding ID from the `#Existing_Employees` table by matching (that's right you guessed it) by the `EMP_ID` columns. So I came up with an extremely hacky way to handle the disparate formats of the `EMP_ID` columns but it is very slow considering the number of rows that I need to process (1M+).

I thought of creating a staging table where I could simply cast the `EMP_ID` columns to an `INT` and then back to a `NVARCHAR` in each table to remove the leading zeros and I am sort of leaning that way but I wanted to see if there was another way to handle this dysfunctional data. Any constructive comments are welcome.

```
        IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB..#NEW_EMPLOYEES') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #NEW_EMPLOYEES

        CREATE TABLE #NEW_EMPLOYEES(
                            ID INT
                            ,EMP_ID NVARCHAR(50)
                            ,NAME NVARCHAR(50))
        GO 

        IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDB..#EXISTING_EMPLOYEES') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #EXISTING_EMPLOYEES

        CREATE TABLE #EXISTING_EMPLOYEES(
                          ID INT PRIMARY KEY
                          ,EMP_ID NVARCHAR(50)
                          ,NAME NVARCHAR(50))
        GO

        INSERT INTO #NEW_EMPLOYEES
        VALUES(NULL, '00123', 'Adam Arkin')
                ,(NULL, '00345', 'Bob Baker')
                ,(NULL, '00526', 'Charles Nelson O''Reilly')
                ,(NULL, '04321', 'David Numberman')
                ,(NULL, '44321', 'Ida Falcone')

    INSERT INTO #EXISTING_EMPLOYEES
        VALUES(1, '123', 'Adam Arkin')
                ,(2, '000345', 'Bob Baker')
                ,(3, '526', 'Charles Nelson O''Reilly')
                ,(4, '0004321', 'Ed Sullivan')
                ,(5, '02143', 'Frank Sinatra')
                ,(6, '5567', 'George Thorogood')
                ,(7, '0000123-1', 'Adam Arkin')
                ,(8, '7', 'Harry Hamilton')

      -- First Method - Not Successful   
        UPDATE NE
            SET ID = EE.ID
        FROM
            #NEW_EMPLOYEES NE
                LEFT OUTER JOIN #EXISTING_EMPLOYEES EE 
                    ON EE.EMP_ID = NE.EMP_ID

        SELECT * FROM #NEW_EMPLOYEES

      -- Second Method - Successful but Slow
        UPDATE NE
            SET ID = EE.ID
        FROM
            dbo.#NEW_EMPLOYEES NE
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.#EXISTING_EMPLOYEES EE 
                    ON CAST(CASE WHEN NE.EMP_ID LIKE N'%[^0-9]%' 
                        THEN NE.EMP_ID 
                        ELSE LTRIM(STR(CAST(NE.EMP_ID AS INT))) END AS NVARCHAR(50)) =
                       CAST(CASE WHEN EE.EMP_ID LIKE N'%[^0-9]%' 
                        THEN EE.EMP_ID 
                        ELSE LTRIM(STR(CAST(EE.EMP_ID AS INT))) END AS NVARCHAR(50))

        SELECT * FROM #NEW_EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: Can you create indexed views to work from? That would give you the benefit of being able to compute the trimmed or numeric id values, where possible, once and index them for performance. Any `like` pattern that starts with a wildcard won't be able to use an index (Except as a faster way to do a table scan.). [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) and [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: No, I am stuck with what I have, they have refused to make changes.

Comment: Could the person who down voted this post please explain?

Comment: Do _they_ understand that a _view_ is not a change to any existing schema or data, just an additional means to access the existing data?

Comment: I have been banging my head against the wall ever since I started working for this company. I can wait until well . . . you know what I mean ;-)

Comment: No I don't see your your problem.  Ask a specific question and identify it with a ? mark.

Comment: So you have authority to change a stored proc, but no authority to create an indexed view?  This makes no sense.  Hard to improve the situation with such foolish restraints.

Comment: Smh DMason! Anyway no I don't have permission to make a change to the SProc I have to make a proposal to the powers that be. Dysfunctional data and dysfunctional org.

Comment: I don't see the point of having multiple formats for your ID column. I think you're just making it difficult on yourself now that you have to mix & match.

Comment: If the difference where the leading zeros **only** it would be rather easy either to convert to INT or to fill all strings with zeros to a given width. But there is one line breaking this concept: Adam Arkin (0000123-1). Are there more IDs with non-int values? How do you handle these? And one more question: You are not allowed to change the existing structure, but are you allowed to add new tables (thinking of an indexed mapping table for the existing employees...)?

Comment: You are stopped from altering TEMP tables? Ridiculous; if you were to (add column(s) .. work with them perhaps adding indexes too .... & remove them)  = a net effect of an unchanged data model is. All within the permitted boundary of updating the SP. Be inventive with your interpretation of the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

> the number of rows that I need to process (1M+).

A million employees?  Per day?

I think I would add a 3rd table:

```
create table #ids ( id INT not NULL PRIMARY KEY
                  , emp_id not NULL NVARCHAR(50) unique );
```

Populate that table using your `LTRIM(STR(CAST`, ahem, *algorithm*, and update Employees directly from a join of those three tables.

I recommend using ANSI **update**, not Microsoft's nonstandard `update ... from` because the ANSI version prevents nondeterministic results in cases where the `FROM` produces more than one row.